# Spring Security OAuth2: DelegatingOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider provides only one type of provider

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, oauth, spring-oauth2

I'm developing a client app using Spring Security OAuth 2.0 Client with resource owner password flow.
I used [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-feign-oauth-token) tutorial as a reference, but with password authorization grant type.

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=password
```

My request looks as follows:

```
OAuth2AuthorizeRequest oAuth2AuthorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest
                .withClientRegistrationId(clientRegistration.getRegistrationId())
                .attributes(attrs -> {
                    attrs.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, username);
                    attrs.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, password);
                    attrs.put(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE);
                })
                .principal(principal)
                .build();
```

This call results in null client:

```
OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = manager.authorize(oAuth2AuthorizeRequest);
```

I'vr debugged the app and found out that *`List<OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider> authorizedClientProviders`* in
*DelegatingOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider* contains only *ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider*. So password provider(PasswordOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider) isn't there and I get null client.

Versions:

- Spring Boot 2.7.10
- Spring Security OAuth Client 5.7.7

Any help is welcomed!

Update:
Fixed *OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider* initialization, but it still looks like there is no support for username/password attributes during context build

```
OAuth2AuthorizationContext authorizationContext = buildAuthorizationContext(authorizeRequest, principal,
            contextBuilder);
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the official documentation, you could try something like this:

```
@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
        ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                    .authorizationCode()
                    .refreshToken()
                    .clientCredentials()
                    .password() // what is needed for you
                    .build();

    DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                    clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
    authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

    return authorizedClientManager;
}
```

for all the detaisl please visit this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/servlet/oauth2/client/index.html)